# Referencing a c# variable inside of MasterpageFile

Tags: asp.net, .net

I read this yesterday and have been switching out my urls to this so it my code is easier to maintain. Ignore the list part. I just have one c# class with all of my urls inside of it.

[.NET - Storing URL's as global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609093/net-storing-urls-as-global-variables)

I'm trying to do something similar with my masterpagefile like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="<%= Urls.masterpage %>" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="test_test" %>
```

I get a parser error that says there are illegal characters in the path. What I'm asking is if there is a work around for this on the front end instead of delving in the c# code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use ASP.NET declarative markup inside ASP.NET declarative markup.

You *may* be able to do it this way instead, but I haven't tested it:

```
<% Page.MasterPageFile = Urls.masterpage; %>
```

Another option is to set it from your codebehind file:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.MasterPageFile = Urls.masterpage;
}
```

Comment: I decided to do it as your recommended in the code behind file.